# iOS Pattern for Settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

When I have an application that has a number of similar views, in, for example a scroll view controller, and an extra view controller for the app settings, and some of these settings should change values on some or all views in the scroll view controller, what is the best way to populate those changes (example: change all units from metric to imperial)?

My attempt at the moment is to reload all views with their content from Core Data and apply the new configuration after a user changed something in the settings, which is slow an uncool, but much more easy and error resistant than looping through the views and updating them one by one.

I am also not sure if I am using Core Data correctly at the moment: I load the stuff on application start in my view controller and init the views in a loop with that data. Is there an easy pattern to connect core data and the views directly so that an update to fields in Core Data directly updates the view data?

How do you solve these problems? Thanks for any tips.

Comment: yes, reload from core data is not good. But you can perform these operations in background OR you can store some valuable variables (like backgroundColor of your controllers) in static class variables. So, it means, that your settings storage moves to memory before Core Data. How about that?

Comment: Also, you can store valuable variables in some Manager classes or Settings Manager classes.

Comment: Like gaussblurinc said, you could implement a settings manager class and store values in it. For the view updating part, you should use the key value observing on your stored values, this way your views will be automatically updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you've got **number of similar views**, I would use UITableViewController with custom cells. It will be faster, use less memory and other.

About settings: Store common settings in NSUserDefaults. Use NSNotificationCenter and add all cells as observers. Don't change data, just change values for cells depending on settings.

When user change this settings:

```
1. Save them to NSUserDefaults.
2. Post notification
3. All lived cells calls method and update proper subviews
```

As we store all settings in NSUserDefaults we'll just take all settings values after following app launches in `viewDidLoad` method for example.